# Maximum number of connections possible with H2 in server mode

Tags: database-connection, h2

I want to insert data from multiple threads to H2 database, I connected the h2 database in Server mode using dbcp connection pooling. 
When I tried to insert data from 2000 threads I got one Exception is

```
"java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?)".
```

So I want to find out two things

1. The maximum number of connections possible ?
2. Can I share connections with multiple threads ?

Answer (score 0):

Default value is 10, but you can set via JDBCConnectionPool. From [docs](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcConnectionPool.html):

```
**JdbcConnectionPool**
setMaxConnections(int max)
   Sets the maximum number of connections to use from now on. The default value is 10 connections.
Parameters:
   max - the maximum number of connections
```

http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcConnectionPool.html

Yes you can share it, if you tell what are you trying to achieve, maybe i can help.

Comment: If we are running h2db in server mode, how do we increase it then?